# How to draw a directed graph with arrows showing vertically from bottom to top

Tags: graphs-and-networks

If I have a directed graph, how can I draw it with arrows pointing vertically from bottom to top, like showing a class inheritance pattern in OOP(object oriented programming)?

For example:

```
Import["http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-eA4znHzAWZw/T_qZ0JdUisI/AAAAAAAAAHg/\
dI_UkYNUxcA/s320/inheritence.png"]
```

[image]

Comment: Does `LayeredGraphPlot` do what you want?

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned by others, you could use `LayeredGraphPlot` for this. However, `LayeredGraphPlot` orders vertices in such a way that directed edges are generally pointing down. To flip the graph over, you could reverse the edges and supply a custom `EdgeRenderingFunction`, e.g.

```
edges = {2 -> 1, 3 -> 1, 4 -> 1, 5 -> 2, 6 -> 1, 7 -> 3, 8 -> 7, 9 -> 8};
LayeredGraphPlot[Reverse /@ edges, DirectedEdges -> True,
 EdgeRenderingFunction -> (Arrow[Reverse[#1], .05] &)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: when I havve a larger data set, the graph is messy, for example, edges = {18 -> 40, 18 -> 25, 19 -> 0, 20 -> 0, 21 -> 2, 21 -> 2, 21 -> 8, 22 -> 1, 22 -> 36, 23 -> 3, 23 -> 31, 23 -> 21, 23 -> 22, 24 -> 3, 24 -> 34, 24 -> 27, 24 -> 40, 25 -> 0, 26 -> 1, 26 -> 8, 27 -> 0, 28 -> 3, 28 -> 35, 28 -> 41, 28 -> 4, 
  29 -> 4, 29 -> 26, 29 -> 40, 29 -> 41, 29 -> 25, 30 -> 1, 30 -> 35, 31 -> 0, 32 -> 0, 33 -> 1, 33 -> 32, 34 -> 1, 34 -> 42, 35 -> 1, 35 -> 37, 36 -> 0, 37 -> 0, 38 -> 1, 38 -> 40, 39 -> 3, 39 -> 41, 39 -> 31, 39 -> 12, 40 -> 0, 41 -> 0, 42 -> 1, 42 -> 17}. How to make it nicer here?

Comment: @QiangLi Try changing the `AspectRatio` and `ImageSize`

Answer (score 6):

You'll need to use [`LayeredGraphPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LayeredGraphPlot.html). Taking an example from the documentation:

```
LayeredGraphPlot[{"Total" -> "TotalDispatch", 
  "TotalList" -> "CheckThreading", "TotalList" -> "TotalDispatch", 
  "TotalSparse" -> "TotalDispatch", "TotalSparse" -> "TotalDispatch", 
  "TotalDispatch" -> "TotalDispatch", "TotalDispatch" -> "TotalList", 
  "TotalDispatch" -> "TotalPacked", "TotalDispatch" -> "TotalSparse"},
  VertexLabeling -> True]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Using `GraphLayout -> {"LayeredDigraphEmbedding", "Orientation" -> Bottom}`:

```
edges = {2 -> 1, 3 -> 1, 4 -> 1, 5 -> 2, 6 -> 1, 7 -> 3, 8 -> 7, 9 -> 8}; 
Graph[edges, GraphStyle -> "SmallNetwork",
 GraphLayout -> {"LayeredDigraphEmbedding", "Orientation" -> Bottom}]
```

[image]

For the second example in the comments:

```
edges2 = {18 -> 40, 18 -> 25, 19 -> 0, 20 -> 0, 21 -> 2, 21 -> 2, 
   21 -> 8, 22 -> 1, 22 -> 36, 23 -> 3, 23 -> 31, 23 -> 21, 23 -> 22, 
   24 -> 3, 24 -> 34, 24 -> 27, 24 -> 40, 25 -> 0, 26 -> 1, 26 -> 8, 
   27 -> 0, 28 -> 3, 28 -> 35, 28 -> 41, 28 -> 4, 29 -> 4, 29 -> 26, 
   29 -> 40, 29 -> 41, 29 -> 25, 30 -> 1, 30 -> 35, 31 -> 0, 32 -> 0, 
   33 -> 1, 33 -> 32, 34 -> 1, 34 -> 42, 35 -> 1, 35 -> 37, 36 -> 0, 
   37 -> 0, 38 -> 1, 38 -> 40, 39 -> 3, 39 -> 41, 39 -> 31, 39 -> 12, 
   40 -> 0, 41 -> 0, 42 -> 1, 42 -> 17};

Graph[edges2, GraphStyle -> "VintageDiagram",
  GraphLayout -> {"LayeredDigraphEmbedding",  "Orientation" -> Bottom}, 
  VertexSize->{.3, .1}, ImageSize->600, AspectRatio->2/3]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Consider the `TreePlot` function. [This page in the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/TreeDrawing.html) should be useful.

One difference between `TreePlot` and `LayeredGraphPlot` (as suggested by R.M.) seems to be that `TreePlot` can handle multiple ''trees'' within the one graph, which might be what you need to trace inheritance in OOP for a large group of functions.

Here is an example lifted directly from the documentation:

```
TreePlot[Table[i -> Mod[i^3, 221], {i, 0, 221}]]
```

[image]

The other difference between `TreePlot` and `LayeredGraphPlot` is that `TreePlot` will lay out the graph without reference to the direction of the edges, if necessary, but `LayeredGraphPlot` is specifically for drawing hierarchical directed graphs.